# How does protocol buffer handle versioning?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

How does protocol buffers handle type versioning?

For example, when I need to change a type definition over time? Like adding and removing fields.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Google designed [protobuf](https://protobuf.dev/) to be pretty forgiving with versioning:

- unexpected data is either stored as "extensions" (making it round-trip safe), or silently dropped, depending on the implementation
- new fields are generally added as "optional", meaning that old data can be loaded successfully

however:

- do not *renumber* fields - that would break existing data
- you should not normally change the way any given field is stored (i.e. from a fixed-width 32-bit int to a "varint")

Generally speaking, though - it will *just work*, and you don't need to worry much about versioning.

Comment: Presumably, removing _required_ fields would also leads to problems?

Comment: @jon it would if passing data to a client that still thought of it as required

Comment: @MarcGravell can you give me any example of handling versions of protobuf

Comment: Versioning support would be a powerful feature, which is lacking in both Google protocol buffer and Thrift. I think this answer is talking about a different concept (tolerance to parameter errors) than type versioning.

Comment: @jon you're best off not having any fields actually defined as "required" for this reason. This issue is discussed in the proto buffer documentation.

Comment: @HaiXinTie No, you missed the point. ProtoBuf was designed in the first place to _prevent_ API version checking: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview#a-bit-of-history

Comment: @m-ric I understand the rationale, but I am not sure that I agree. With versioning, not only new fields can be introduced, but old fields can be deprecated as well in a clean way, not so in a proto. Proto3 has removed "required" for this specific reason, as they are confusing and risky to change without the concept of versioning (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801257/why-required-and-optional-is-removed-in-protocol-buffers-3). Self-describing format can also be done with versioning, so I don't consider it a strength of the protobuf.

Comment: @HaiXinTie I understand your point. I don't call it a strength or a weakness. It is just a design decision we have to understand and live with :-)

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into this recently. The way I got around it is using facades, and run-time decisions to serialize. This way I can deprecate/upgrade a field into a new type, with old and new messages handling it gracefully.

I am using Marc Gravell's protobuf.net (v2.3.5), and C#, but the theory of facades would work for any language and Google's original protobuf implementation.

My old class had a Timestamp of DateTime which I wanted to change to include the "Kind" (a .NET anachronism). Adding this effectively meant it serialized to 9 bytes instead of 8, which would be a breaking serialization change!

```
    [ProtoMember(3, Name = "Timestamp")]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
```

A fundamental of protobuf is NEVER to change the proto ids! I wanted to read old serialized binaries, which meant "3" was here to stay.

So,

I renamed the old property and made it private (yes, it can still deserialize through reflection magic), but my API no longer shows it useable!

```
    [ProtoMember(3, Name = "Timestamp-v1")]
    private DateTime __Timestamp_v1 = DateTime.MinValue;
```

I created a new Timestamp property, with a new proto id, and included the DateTime.Kind

```
    [ProtoMember(30002, Name = "Timestamp", DataFormat = ProtoBuf.DataFormat.WellKnown)]
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
```

I added a "AfterDeserialization" method to update our new time, in the case of old messages

```
    [ProtoAfterDeserialization]
    private void AfterDeserialization()
    {
        //V2 Timestamp includes a "kind" - we will stop using __Timestamp - so keep it up to date
        if (__Timestamp_v1 != DateTime.MinValue)
        {
            //Assume the timestamp was in UTC - as it was...
            Timestamp = new DateTime(__Timestamp_v1.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc)     //This is for old messages - we'll update our V2 timestamp...
        }
    }
```

Now, I have the old and new messages serializing/deserializing correctly, and my Timestamp now includes DateTime.Kind! Nothing broken.

However, this does mean that BOTH fields will be in all new messages going forward. So the final touch is to use a run-time serialization decision to exclude the old Timestamp (note this won't work if it was using protobuf's required attribute!!!)

```
    bool ShouldSerialize__Timestamp_v1() 
    {
        return __Timestamp_v1 != DateTime.MinValue;
    }
```

And thats it. I have a nice unit test which does it from end-to-end if anyone wants it...

I know my method relies on .NET magic, but I reckon the concept could be translated to other languages....

Comment: No apology needed for addressing an old question.  It's not like they rot, and the next devs along get the benefit of your experience.  Thank you!

Comment: +1, But I'd not call it migration.
It's just a code that can will run on every serialization, regardless if object is old or not.
It can blow up in future, i.e if that field would be used again.
Yes proto allows to reserve old values, but keeping old useless trash in code is hardly a good decision.
Migration on the other hand must only run if scheme version was changed and only once