# What are the implications of using Swift Codable on the evolution of the conforming type?

Tags: swift, serialization

As I am learning about the `Codable` protocol of Swift 4 and thinking about how this can be used, I want to understand what are the implications on the potential future evolution of a type when making it `Codable`.

In usual code, if I change a type by adding a property to it, I just need to update my local codebase to react to this change (by adding a new argument to my type initialiser calls for instance).

On the other hand, if my type had been `Codable` and I had already used it in combination with a distant server (by sending and receiving this type encoded as JSON) wouldn't it be pretty problematic to add new properties ?

For instance, say that I receive a JSON encoded by the previous version of my app (that was still stored by the server), and I try to decode it with the new version, the decoding process will fail as the data for the new property won't be available.

How should I deal with such situations ?
"Locking" my type at some point, forbidding it to evolve in the future ?
What would be the cleanest way to decode incompatible data if it was really needed ?

Comment: Related: [What is the best way to handle versioning using JSON protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10042742)

Comment: @JoshCaswell That's interesting ! But that doesn't seem to solve the issue of receiving a JSON encoded by a previous version, does it ?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Since in Swift all properties must be initialised, the only solution I would see is to make the new properties optional, but I don't know how the automatic decoding process would react to this...

Comment: If your new field is not required, declare it to be optional and `Decodable` will gracefully handle its absence in JSON. If it's not optional and does not have a default value, then it's obviously not a backwards-compatible change. And if its a new property completely unrelated to what is exchanged with the web service, you might explicitly declare your `CodingKeys` and omit this field from that so it doesn't factor into `Decodable` at all.

Comment: I just said it was related! :) Not that it had all the answers.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes thank you !! :)

Comment: @Rob Oh that's really interesting, especially how `Decodable` handles nil, didn't knew it was so easy ! Thank you ! :)